# In nuxt2 fetch method throws "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I welcome everyone! Faced such a problem, when I create the fetch method in the Nuxt2 component, I get the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" the stack trace does not show anything good

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import BaseModal from '~/components/Business/Modal/BaseModal.vue';
import ModalForm from '~/components/UI/Form/ModalForm.vue';
import ModalFormInput from '~/components/UI/FormElements/Input/ModalFormInput.vue';
import BaseButton from '~/components/UI/FormElements/Button/BaseButton.vue';
import ModalSwitcher from '~/components/Business/Switch/ModalSwitcher.vue';
import ChangeInputService from '~/services/ui/input/change-input-service';
import InputService from '~/services/ui/input/input-service';
import AuthService from '~/services/business/security/auth-service';
import Routes from '~/api/routes';
import ApiRequestService from '~/services/business/api-request-service';
import GoogleAuthUrlRequest from '~/api/requests/google-auth-url-request';

@Component({
  components: {
    BaseModal,
    ModalForm,
    ModalFormInput,
    BaseButton,
    ModalSwitcher
  },

  async fetch() {} // Maximum call stack size exceeded
})
export default class AuthModal extends Vue {
  private googleAuthUrl: string | null = null;

  private readonly changeInputService: ChangeInputService = new ChangeInputService({
    email: new InputService('', 'string', undefined, 1),
    password: new InputService('', 'string', undefined, 1)
  });

  private readonly authService: AuthService = new AuthService(this);
  private buttonIsLoading: boolean = false;

  public async mounted(): Promise<void> {
    await this.socialNetworkAuth();
  }

  private async socialNetworkAuth(): Promise<void> {
    const query = this.$route.query;

    if ('code' in query && 'state' in query) {
      const modal = this.$refs.modal as BaseModal;

      modal.open();
      modal.setIsLoading(true);

      await this.authService.socialNetworkAuth(
        Routes.social_auth.google.auth,
        query.code as string
      );
    }
  }

  private async auth(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.changeInputService.allFieldsWithoutErrors()) {
      this.buttonIsLoading = true;

      await this.authService.auth({
        email: this.changeInputService.getInput('email').getValue(),
        password: this.changeInputService.getInput('password').getValue()
      });

      this.buttonIsLoading = false;
    }
  }
}
```

If you remove this method, the error disappears, in addition, this error appears even if there is nothing inside the fetch

I tried to replace it with asynData, but asyncData does not work in components, it is intended only for page components

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, no need to initialize the properties right away, they need to be initialized through the `created` hook